# Is using HTTPS in Android WebView flawed, if used for device hosted HTML pages?

Tags: ajax, ssl, https, cross-domain, csrf

It is my belief that if you use HTTPS with locally hosted pages, making Ajax requests to secure servers, it is either not possible or flawed.

The reason I think so, is because we are no longer in the domain (say https://securewebsite.com) , rather on a local page, accessing a secure server.

This is just something I "think", and I would really appreciate it if someone can point out any mistakes in assuming that.

Comment: You should use the android tag.

Comment: Is it an HTTP header?